# Taking parameters from two different objects to insert into a database with php/sql

Tags: php, sql, object

I'm trying to create a 'CD Store' program, where I want to store credit card details on a database, but I want the database to reference the user's ID where I have created elsewhere. How can I pass a parameter from another object to a new one? I tried to write the code but I keep getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CDStore/creditCardAccess.php on line 36
```

I know that it is possibly not being referenced, and the $user variable is showing up yellow in netbeans. I'm not sure how will I go about this? any pointers would be much appreciated. Here is my code thanks

```
<?php

class creditCardAccess {

protected $link;

public function __construct() {
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "CDStore";

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";

    $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

public function __destruct() {
    $this->link = null;
}
public function insertCreditCard($creditCard) {
    if (!isset($creditCard) && $creditCard != null) {
        throw new Exception("Credit Card Required");
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO creditCards(cardType, cardName, cardNumber, cardExpiryDate, cardCCV, userID)"
            . "VALUES (:cardType, :cardName, :cardNumber, :cardExpiryDate, :cardCCV, :userID)";

    $params = array(
        'cardType' => $creditCard->getCardType(),
        'cardName' => $creditCard->getCardName(),
        'cardNumber' => $creditCard->getCardNumber(),
        'cardExpiryDate' => $creditCard->getCardExpiryDate(),
        'cardCCV' => $creditCard->getCardCCV(),
        'userID' => $user->getId()
    );

    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    $status = $stmt->execute($params);
    if ($status != true) {
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        throw new Exception("Could Not Add Credit Card: " . $errorInfo[2]);
    }

    $id = $this->link->lastInsertId('creditCard');
    $creditCard->setId($id);
}

}
?>
```

line 36 is 'userID' => $user->getId()

Comment: You should be storing the credit card details as plain text - at least use the MD crypt function to encrypt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your $user object should be passed in as a parameter to the function, otherwise you will never have visibility to $user

```
public function insertCreditCard($creditCard, $user) {
```

Comment: Thanks Zak, I thought I had tried that earlier, but maybe I had a misspelling. worked like a treat!

Answer (score 1):

First include your user class in this file. Then in create a user property in the class. In the constructor create an instance of the user class. Then you can use the user class functions.

```
<?php

require_once("user.class.php"); //the user management class path

class creditCardAccess {

protected $link;

var $user;

public function __construct() {
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "CDStore";

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";

    $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->user = new User();
}

public function __destruct() {
    $this->link = null;
}
public function insertCreditCard($creditCard) {
    if (!isset($creditCard) && $creditCard != null) {
        throw new Exception("Credit Card Required");
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO creditCards(cardType, cardName, cardNumber, cardExpiryDate, cardCCV, userID)"
            . "VALUES (:cardType, :cardName, :cardNumber, :cardExpiryDate, :cardCCV, :userID)";

    $params = array(
        'cardType' => $creditCard->getCardType(),
        'cardName' => $creditCard->getCardName(),
        'cardNumber' => $creditCard->getCardNumber(),
        'cardExpiryDate' => $creditCard->getCardExpiryDate(),
        'cardCCV' => $creditCard->getCardCCV(),
        'userID' => $user->getId()
    );

    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    $status = $stmt->execute($params);
    if ($status != true) {
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        throw new Exception("Could Not Add Credit Card: " . $errorInfo[2]);
    }

    $id = $this->link->lastInsertId('creditCard');
    $creditCard->setId($id);
}

}
?>
```